# How to create a build.gradle that builds three versions of a Spring Boot application - one with Tomcat, one with Jetty, one with Undertow embedded

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jetty, undertow

We would like to diversify our production environment and deploy our application instances with different embedded application containers/servers: One instance with Tomcat, one with Jetty and one with Undertow.

Our code does not use anything container-specific, and manually swapping the embedded containers by using a different spring-boot-start dependency works fine.

Is it possible to create a build.gradle that creates three build artifacts (executable JAR files), one for each container? If so - how?

Comment: Why? Why the added complexity? You can probably do that by using 3 differnt build profiles or something (probably something in there like that not sure). But from a functional point of view it doesn't add anything to be able to have 3 different runtimes.

Comment: If you are using spring-boot, you are baking in the container in an embedded fashion, there's no "for each container" deployable anymore.  The overhead you are incurring with all of the niggling configuration knobs that spring-boot does not expose is going to drive you insane with this sort of setup.  You'll quickly wind up with 3 different projects with 3 different build.gradle's

Comment: @m-deinum : We would like to do this so that our production environment is more diverse; so if there is a problem with Tomcat (security breach, ...) we can simply bring down the instances with embedded Tomcats and continue running the Jetty- and Undertow-based instances. This is actually a common practice; we are running some of our services on different OSs for exactly that reason: If there is a severe problem with Linux, our FreeBSD instances can continue to handle traffic and vice versa. About the build profiles: How would you go about it?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: I know that the containers are embedded - that's not the point. Besides, you can still build traditional WARs for deployment. We are looking for a way to trigger one build that than builds three versions of our application: One with an embedded Tomcat, one with an embedded Jetty, and one with an embedded Undertow. I am aware that these will be three different executable JARs. Do you know how to do this?